# VBA scraping generated content which is not in the HTML source file

Tags: javascript, vba, web-scraping

I have made a VBA code to scrape some product prices from web pages.

I can make it work for all the websites I want except for one. On this particular site, the prices are not shown in the HTML code of the page, but they are locally generated by JavaScript, as far as I understood from searching the net.

How can I scrape these prices?

I'm using this method to get the page source and then I parse the response text to get the information I need, like product name and link, but I can't get the prices:

```
Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

        adresa = "http://www.elefant.ro/carti/natura"
        With xhr

            .Open "GET", adresa, False
            .send

            If .readyState = 4 And .Status = 200 Then
                Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
                corp = .responseText
            Else
                Cells(i, 2) = "error"
            End If
        End With
```

Here is an part of the HTML code of the page I'm getting, where the prices should be:

```
<div class="js_PriceContainer" style="display: none">
            <div>
                <div class="product_old_price js_oldPrice">
                    <a class="FFTracking" rel=""  href="/carti/natura/resurse-naturale/ghidul-culegatorului-de-ciuperci-211009.html"><span class="js_basePrice"></span> lei</a>
                </div>

                <div class="product_discount js_ProductDiscount">
                    <a class="FFTracking" rel=""  href="/carti/natura/resurse-naturale/ghidul-culegatorului-de-ciuperci-211009.html">(<span class="js_discount"></span>%)</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- <div class="promo_bf">
                                            <div class="product_old_price"></div>
                        <div class="product_discount"></div>
                                    </div> -->

            <div style="clear:both"></div>
            <div class="product_final_price js_FinalPriceContainer">
                <a class="FFTracking" rel=""  href="/carti/natura/resurse-naturale/ghidul-culegatorului-de-ciuperci-211009.html">
                    <span class="js_finalPrice js_promoNonBf"></span>
                    <span class="js_finalPrice js_promoBf"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: if you need to read dynamic content generated on the client then you should (eg) automate IE to load the page and use automation to read the content.  If you use the IE Developer tools then you should be able to view the rendered content (as opposed to only the HTML delivered from the server)

Answer (score 0):

Import [QT WebKit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebkit-index.html) in your project and use the power of webkit to render webpages before scraping. [This guide](https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/) explains how webkit is implemented in LXML **scraper** .

Comment: Thank you, but after reading the quide I can tell you that it's beyond my amateur programmer skills... Is there a simpler verion?

Comment: If this is not a programming project, aren't ready scrappers useful?

Comment: I would preffer programming, so I could also learn something.